# How do I duplicate a build list on Newegg?

Tags: newegg

I have a public build list on Newegg with parts for building a new computer.

I'd like to start deleting items from the list to keep track of which parts I have and haven't ordered yet. However, I still want to keep my original build list intact to refer back to.

Essentially, I want to keep two build lists: one original with every part for my PC, and one copy which only includes the parts I haven't ordered yet.

Is there a way I can duplicate my build list on Newegg?